# Qt Creator and Qstring

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to programming and using qt to create my own GUI. I'm trying to make a search bar one of my list view's but it keeps saying that there is no matching function to call... This may be a really stupid question. Here is my code.

```
void Widget::on_SearchBar_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{

    QString Input;
    ui->Online->find(Input);
}
```

and the error

> C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\CryptoCourier\widget.cpp:21: error: no matching function for call to 'QListWidget::find(QString&)'

```
ui->Online->find(Input);
```

here is the rest of my code as requested

Ok So here is the rest of my code. Not much but  here.

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_CryptoCC.h"
#include <QString>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::on_SearchBar_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
   #include <string>
    QString Input;
    ui->Online->find(Input);
}
                       ^
```

Comment: You're calling the `find` method of your QListWidget instance `Online`. This method is described here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#find. It does not have anything to do with search, but rather mapping native widget handles back to QWidgets (and it doesn't take a QString argument). Maybe include a small UI mockup of what you're trying to accomplish and then people will be able to be of more help.

Comment: Tip: you cannot write programs by putting together random stuff; first learn the language, then some basics of the Qt framework, and always read the documentation of the methods you don't know.

Comment: Oh yeah. I forgot to take that out. I had fixed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two major problems:

- `#include` statements should go outside of functions, since they literally **include** an entire file exactly where you put them.
- For [`QString`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html), the file you want to include is probably called "QString".

Try something like this:

```
#include <QString>

/* the rest of your code, which you didn't include in your example */

void Widget::on_SearchBar_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    /* by the way, you're calling Online->find() with an empty string,
     * did you mean to use `arg1` here? */
    QString Input;
    ui->Online->find(Input);
}
```

Beyond that, I'd need to know what `ui` and `ui->Online` are before I could give you advice about what functions you can call on them.